# Implement "OR" constraints in CVXPY

Tags: python, constraints, constraint-programming, cvxpy

So I have a quick question which I was not able to find the answer to...

I want to implement an "OR" constraint on CVXPY:

Either x = 0  OR  x_min < x < x_max

where x is a real positive value. How can we implement such a constraint in code?
I was trying to formulate the constraint with a mixed-integer form, but I was unsuccessful...
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no *strict* inequalities in convex-optimization.

Assuming, we want to express:

```
Either x = 0 OR x_min <= x <= x_max
(x_min, x_max: scalar constants)
```

this is usually done by (mixed-integer programming!):

```
Add binary variable y
Add constraint: x <= x_max * y
Add constraint: x >= x_min * y
```

Strict inequalities would need a-priori defined *epsilons*.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So is "y" an optimization variable? By binary, you mean that "y" should be 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes. It's a new binary variable (0 or 1) added to the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated.